# How to get Viber desktop ads to go away

Tags: advertisements, viber

Viber desktop has been great up until the past couple of weeks. Now the ads in the bottom under contacts are video ads and they're making Viber lock up so badly. It jilts the typing 99% of the time too. So nothing is smooth. They're by Adchoices and my computer is clean as a whistle so I know it's not my computer. How do I disable them? I saw another post about adding to the host file but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 11):

1. Open notepad as administrator = right click on the notepad icon and select Run as administrator.
2. Go to the menu File -> Open.
3. Navigate to this file and open it:

   ```
   C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
   ```
4. Add the following line:

   > ```
   > 127.0.0.1 ads.viber.com
   > ```
5. Save the file and exit notepad.

Comment: Will require Viber restart. May need to temporarily turn off antivirus if it doesn't allow to save the changes.

Answer (score 1):

new ads server to block
Add a firewall rule in your router to block the following domains:

1. ads-d.viber.com
2. ads.aws.viber.com
3. ads.viber.com
4. s-bid.rmp.rakuten.com
5. s-imp.rmp.rakuten.com
6. api.mixpanel.com
7. api.taboola.com
8. ams1-mobile.adnxs.com
9. mediation.adnxs.com
10. fra1-ib.adnxs.com
11. mobile.anycast.adnxs.com
12. mobile.geo.appnexusgslb.net